# Optional props in custom typescript hook

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to allow for optional props on a custom hook that have a default value if not passed in, but I keep getting typescript errors.

```
interface IProps {
  start: number,
  timeout: 2000,
}

const useCustomHook = ({start = 10, timeout= 500 }: IProps | null) => {
 ....
});
```

I'm getting an error on start and timeout

```
Property 'start' does not exist on type 'IProps | null'.
```

**Component.js** 
I want to be able to pass in the props or leave it empty null.

```
const [value] = useCustomHook();

The error i'm getting is Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it to a non-null values and allow optionals by using `Partial`.

## Fixed

```
interface IProps {
  start: number,
  timeout: number,
}

const useCustomHook = ({ start = 10, timeout = 500 }: Partial<IProps> = {}) => {
 // ....
  console.log(start, timeout);
};
```

Comment: What does Partial<IProps> do ?